# merge deprecation warning confusion

Tags: rxjs

Using RXJS I have the following

```
      merge(this.optionValueChanged$, this.options.changes).subscribe(() => {
        this.selectionByValue(this.pValue)
      }),
```

now, on hover this return

> @deprecated — use {@link scheduled} and {@link mergeAll} (e.g. `scheduled([ob1, ob2, ob3], scheduled).pipe(mergeAll())

but I read about scheduled, and it looks like it's not exactly doing what I want. Also, I can't figure out what those the `scheduled` inside the method `scheduled` stand for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Typescript selects the wrong overload. Only the overloads that accept `SchedulerLike` are deprecated.

Try to change the order of your parameters

```
merge(this.options.changes, this.optionValueChanged$)
```

Or wrap them in an array and spread

```
merge(...[this.optionValueChanged$, this.options.changes])
```

Comment: That's right, even when not all overloads are deprecated you could get a deprecation message from the function's JSDoc due to the way this functionality picks up these messages. A related issue is discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40007

Comment: According to the question title, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Also ran into this, was solved when I explicitly defined the parameter types before passing into `merge`.

i.e.

```
const obs1: ObservableInput<any> = ...
const obs2: ObservableInput<any> = ...
return merge(obs1, obs2).pipe(...)
```

Comment: helpful, as typescript selects the wrong overload when the type is `any`

Answer (score 2):

I agree, that is confusing. I always saw it as some kind of `any` in that way, that this is a placeholder for an observable which emits other observables.

Have a look on this example

```
const ob1 = of(1).pipe(delay(5000));
const ob2 = of(2).pipe(delay(1000));
const ob3 = of(3).pipe(delay(2000));

function schedule() {
  return of(ob1, ob2, ob3);
}

schedule().pipe(
  mergeAll(),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

It has the same functionality as merge, the 1 is printed last, because it is emitted last.

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z6t8yn?file=index.ts

Comment: Thank for the clarification.
So basically I should use this 6 line thing instead of the one line ?

Comment: No, I splitted it just for clarification. Transfer `merge(ob1, ob2, ob3)` to `of(ob1, ob2, ob3).pipe(mergeAll())`

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I don't think he should change `merge(ob1, ob2, ob3)` at all. Static merge isn't deprecated. As mentioned in another answer, typescript selects the wrong overload, and wrongly gives a deprecation warning. So, you're absolutely right about how to get by without `merge()`, there just isn't really a need to.